# When running specs with RSpec in Rails, how do I access the test_database concurrently via the rails console or an external script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

With RSpec, I'm trying to test a Rails program that calls an external python script.  When running the spec, RSpec has access to the test database *rails_program_test*. However, the python script cannot access the database *rails_program_test*.

Furthermore, while running rails console test in a separate terminal, queries show no records in the test database, even though the spec reports that records do exist.  Finally, when I switch the RAILS_ENV to development, the python script has access to the *rails_program_development* database.  Is there a way to access the test database outside of the spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because the Rails app is using transactional fixtures. They are rolled back at the end of each test, so are never visible to external processes.

You might want to look at the DatabaseCleaner gem for a non-transactional approach, but your use case sounds very unusual.

Comment: This worked.  Thank you Andy.  The main setting was:  `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` and then using the conventional setup for database_cleaner.  I added a meta-tag 'trunc' to specify this strategy:     `config.before(:each, trunc: true) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation }`